# SSRS not loaded dll from .NET framework 4.5

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I've created *.dll* in .NET Framework 4.5 and put it into `SQL Server - Reporting Services - Report Server - Bin` folder, and when deploy report from developer machine, i got this error:

```
Error while loading code module: ‘{namespace}, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’.
Details: Could not load file or assembly '{namespace}, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

Can someone explainme what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you deploying on a different machine? If so what version of .NET Framework is installed on that machine?

Comment: Hm, .NET Framework on that machine is 3.5, and yes, I deploy on different machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded
>   runtime and cannot be loaded.

It seems like your assembly is built using newer version of `.NET Framework (4.5)` which is not installed on the machine where you are deploying your solution.

Either install the `.NET Framework version 4.5` or build your assembly using a version which is installed on the server.